# Caching - core.css/corev4.css

Tags: master-page, css, 2007

For every SharePoint page, the browser loads a new instance of the core.css (or corev4.css) file.

Is there a way, in the Master Page, to enable caching for this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the browser loads a new instance everytime? becasue i think it already cashes all the heavy files like core, ribbon css as well as all the js files.

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: Update: I took a closer look, and you're right: the file name and revision number stay the same when you navigate a site. Thanks!